# How to get specific strings from html file to use in App

Tags: java, android, html

I got a html file index.html which looks like this:

```
0101111Item1 9110110Item2 1120111Item3 0130103Item4 0110103Item5 0110109Item6 ...
```

I finally made it to put this into a string named content1:

```
setContentView(R.layout.last);
T1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.T1);
    StringBuilder content1 = new StringBuilder();


   try {
           URL url = new URL("http://website/index.html");
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
           String str;
           while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

            content.append(str +"\n");
            T1.setText(content1);

           }
           in.close();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e){
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

which gives me the output one item under the last. And thats fine for me.

There are some CheckBoxes to decide how the user wants to filter e.g.
First question 1, Second question 2, Third question 1 + 2 which leads to a 9 im my code, Forth question no filter which leads also to 9 in my code.
So i got an extra string that looks like userfilter = 1009011. I also put every singleposition of the filterresults in a variable(var1, var2,var3,...var6,var7).

Now I want to filter and thats where I am stuck. In my "No programmer brain" it looks like this:

```
if var1 = 1 
result = result + text from content1 where first digit = 1
if var1 = 0 
result = result + text from content1 where first digit = 0
if var1 = 9
result = result + text from content1 where first digit = everything

if var2 = 1
result = result + text from content1 where second digit = 1
...
```

Ok guys, sorry for the wall of text. I hope you see what i'm looking for. Just to add a little information for those who wonder: English is not my first language and i'm an absolute beginner in the programming field.

Comment: Does the file read have anything to do with your question which sounds like parsing using regular expression or substring to me

Comment: In the end i want to filter through a string. I wrote the part with the file because maybe there is a simplier way of getting a solution. Html stuff or something like filtering on the website and get the filtered stuff to my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem right:

[String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
`String[] a = content1.split("\n")` will give you an array of strings -- in fact, this will be the lines that you packed into one string, you could store them into, say, an ArrayList and avoid the need to split the line.

`for(String s:a) if (s.startsWith(prefix)) { ... }` will iterate over the array and filter items of interest.

To accumulate them: [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) 
`ArrayList results = new ArrayList()` and to add a string to the array: `results.add(s)`

Comment: That's it. Thanks for understanding and replying fast  and correct!